# Problem with Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin and relative pathes in HTML report file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the Jenkins `HTML Publisher Plugin` for publishing HTML test reports to the job and build. The test reports and error screenshots I add after every build to the artifacts. And later I use the `HTML Publisher Plugin` to link to the report HTML file in the artifacts.

The test reports contain the error screenshots with relative pathes `src="./../errorShots/ERROR_screenshot_2019-06-04_02:19:29:529.png"`. And it is running when I open the report HTML file directly under the artifacts in the specific jenkins builds. Then the images are correctly visible.

But when I'm using the `HTML Publisher Plugin` to link to exactly this test report HTML file the relative pathes are not working. So, the links to the embedded images are not working anymore and the images are not visible, because the relative link path seems to be wrong.

So, how can I solve the problem? I think the plugins does not create only a link to the target HTML file. If it would do that it should running with relative pathes in HTML report file.